# Redirect every page to correct page

Tags: redirect

My fist website was made on extension .be
Now my new website is on extension .com

When building my new website I've made sure that all the page names where the same as on my old site.

My old site has a pretty good listing on Google. But all the links on Google are pointing to my .be but as I deleted my site on .be I get all error 404.

I know how to redirect my homepage. But how do I redirect the other pages?

```
<?php
header( "Status: 301 Moved Permanently" );
header( "Location: https://www.example.com" );
exit(0); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Friend
You can use .htaccess for redirect on particular page OR URL 
Reference site: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/htaccess-redirect.htm